# How can i add a day to check-out?

Tags: javascript, html

I am doing a check-in/check-out datepicker. Check-in date picker is working but the problem is that the check-out one is allowing me to select check-in (and of course is not possible to check-out in the same day of check-in). So i want to add a day to check-out but i dont know how...
Can someone help me

This is the code i have:

```js
  var today = new Date();

        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
        if (dd < 10) {
            dd = '0' + dd
        }
        if (mm < 10) {
            mm = '0' + mm
        }

        today = yyyy + '-' + mm + '-' + dd;

        document.getElementById("datainicio").setAttribute("min", today);
        document.getElementById("datainicio").onchange = function () {

            var input = document.getElementById("datafim");

            input.min = document.getElementById("datainicio").value;

        }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
        <h4>Data Inicio</h4>
        <p><input type="date" name="datainicio" id="datainicio"></p>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h4>Data Fim</h4>
        <p><input type="date" id="datafim" name="datafim"></p>
    </div>
```

Translations:

```
datainicio=check-in
datafim=check-out
```

Comment: `is not possible to check-out in the same day of check-in` why not?

Comment: Hi, congratulations on your first question! What you will want to do here is start by adding a listener on the "datafim" element that will update its value.

Comment: why not? can you book an hotel for 12 hours? Here in portugal we can't...

Comment: Imenus, something like document.getElementById("datafim").addEventListener?

Answer (score 2):

Would [momentjs](https://momentjs.com/) be helpful to you? It is a small load to carry, but VERY helpful with dates in js.

Your code would then be something like this...

```
    checkin = moment( pickeddate ).format( "YYYY-MM-DD" );
    checkout = moment( pickeddate ).add('days', 1).format( "YYYY-MM-DD" );
```

Just a thought.

Comment: So instead of all that code (except div) i just use those 2 lines? and where do i insert the id?

Comment: Something along the lines of 
`document.getElementById("datainicio").addEventListener( 'change',function(){document.getElementById("datafim").setAttribute("min", moment( this.value ).add('days', 1).format( "YYYY-MM-DD" ));});`
would, I think, do it.